# Would one e breaking PCI compliance in this scenario?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

**First and foremost** - I am not planning on going down the road of trying to adhere to PCI compliance myself, It's simply not worth the headache. I am however interested in how some companies manage to do this.

**Here's the scenario:**

- *A standard marketplace setup with vendors selling their own items and customers purchasing them.*
- *Storing customer card details upon checkout*
- *Later displaying a customers full card details to vendors who can
  then process the transaction via their own methods*
- *All whilst following PCI compliance for this particular setup*

Would one be breaking PCI compliance in any way and/or would this be putting the vendors at any sort of risk?

Also, are the any third-party services that would take care of storing the card data to then get via something like a web-hook? (stripe etc only return the last 4 digits)

Comment: Why are you delaying processing payment? Why are you capturing payment details then passing it on to the vendor who then passes it on to the card company? This does not appear to be a typical "marketplace" at all.

Comment: It would appear to be trivial to connect to a payment processor who handles all this for the vendors.

Comment: @schroeder By typical I mean vendors add their own products etc. Also, as I said at the beginning of the question. This isn't something that I'm actually doing. We will in fact be processing cards upon checkout. And, as I said, I'm simply interested in how others are doing this.

Comment: If the vendor needs you to pass on the CVV code, then this would violate PCI-DSS (it cannot be stored at all)

Comment: You can store the CVV before processing apparently.

Comment: You can indeed. You can also store all of this data via a third party vault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to this after some more research. It turns out there are services available that store card details via tokenization for you in what's usually called a vault.

By doing so you vastly reduce the scope of PCI compliance on your side of the application.

Here's a few of those services to anyone who's looking: 
AuricVault: https://www.auricsystems.com/auricvault/
Spreedly (you can't de-toeknize but still can store): https://www.spreedly.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be possible. I know of a level one service provider doing basically as you describe. I think it’s a bad idea myself, since you rely on customers to be security conscious, and I would think it opens their PCI scope to SAQ D (which they probably don’t realise). Having said that it’s likely the customers responsibility to be PCI compliant and use PCI compliance service providers. So technically should be fine but feels like you’re playing with fire.

Try Spreedly, they let you use different gateways and also have a vault, not sure about getting the full PAN though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found speedily and they unfortunately don't allow you to de-tokenize any details.